# MySQL procedure stops after exactly 50 loops wir error "Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

If have the following procedure and it stops exactly after 50 loops with the error "Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now". I played around and it seems to be no timeout issue. Any ideas?

```
## Prozedur Droppen
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ifob.uspCreateViewFromTable;

## Prozedur erstellen
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `uspCreateViewFromTable`(IN ViewName varchar(255), IN TableName varchar(255))
BEGIN

  -- DECLARE column varchar(500);
  DECLARE colname varchar(500);
  DECLARE done BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

  DECLARE column_cursor CURSOR FOR
  SELECT column_name
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = Tablename;
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

  #View Droppen falls sie schon erstellt wurde
  SET @s = CONCAT('DROP VIEW IF EXISTS ',ViewName);
  PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
  #Init
  SET @used = 'Used:';
  SET @unused = 'Unused:';
  #Loop through columns
  OPEN column_cursor;
  read_loop: LOOP
      FETCH column_cursor INTO colname;
      SET @c=CONCAT('SELECT COUNT(`',colname, '`) INTO @outvar FROM (SELECT `',colname,'` FROM ',TableName,' WHERE `',colname,'` != 0 OR `',colname,'` != null  ORDER BY `Time` DESC LIMIT 0,10) AS temp');

      PREPARE stmt FROM @c;
      EXECUTE stmt;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

      IF @outvar>0 THEN
        SET @used = CONCAT(@used,';',colname);
      ELSE
        SET @unused = CONCAT(@unused, ';', colname);
      END IF;
      #debug
      SELECT @used UNION SELECT @unused; 

      IF done THEN
        LEAVE read_loop;
      END IF;
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE column_cursor;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there seems to be a problem with loops in MySQL stored procedures that limits the number of selects that have an output to 50. Try to remove

```
SELECT @used UNION SELECT @unused;
```

and see if your procedure is able to run then. Select ... into doesn't seems to have this problem, so you can execute how many you want of them.

Comment: Indeed, I solved but it in that way but where is this limit of 50 coming from? I searched for a parameter to adjust it but I could'd find anything.

Comment: I have not been able to find out the reason behind this limit of 50 either. My best guess at the moment is that it is has something to do with the driver, but I have not tested that yet.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a problem with earlier versions of MySQL workbench. Upgrade to the MySQL Workbench 6.3.7 release

There was a bug filed https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77470.

"Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.3.7 release, and here's the changelog entry:
Workbench will now prompt to continue the execution of operations
containing loops in stored procedures, instead of just canceling it after
~200 executions.

Thank you for the bug report."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. When I extracted the code and ran it in Workbench
it looked like it was calling the stored procedure for each loop.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TestLoop()
BEGIN
DECLARE done int DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE DetId integer;
DECLARE DetSeq tinyint;
DECLARE ItemId smallint;
DECLARE Cnt smallint DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE Total smallint DEFAULT 0;

DECLARE SaleItem CURSOR FOR SELECT SalDetSalId, SalDetSeq, SalDetInvId FROM SaleDetail WHERE SalDetCost = 0;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SaleDetail WHERE SalDetCost = 0 INTO Total;

OPEN SaleItem;

read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH SaleItem INTO DetId, DetSeq, ItemId;
    IF done THEN LEAVE read_loop; END IF;
    SET Cnt=Cnt+1;
    SELECT DetId, DetSeq, ItemId, Cnt, Total;
END LOOP read_loop;

CLOSE SaleItem;
SELECT Cnt, Total;
END; //
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to attach an image. So, the screenshot is at http://SwensonStudio.com/ScreenShot.jpg